# How does oobleck work?

Tags: mixtures, home-experiment

[Oobleck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-newtonian_fluid#Oobleck) is basically a mixture of cornstarch and water. It has the interesting property of going hard when pressure is applied. For example, it feels like a liquid when you swirl your fingers through it, but it becomes hard for a second if you punch it.

The common explanation for this is that the starch-water mixture is a [suspension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_%28chemistry%29), and the  starch particles "lock" when pressure is applied.

What exactly is the mechanism of this "locking"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wikipedia already offers a [decent summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilatant#Theories_behind_shear_thickening_behavior) of two theories of shear thickening behavior - namely the generation of transient 'defects' in a high-density suspension that either resist further growth or are incompressible in the direction of shear.

A potential macroscale analogue of shear thickening is the dramatic increase in viscosity of large particle-air mixtures upon pneumatic removal of the interparticle fluid, as is exploited in [jamming skin enabled locomotion](http://www.youtube.com/embed/SbqHERKdlK8). (paper [here](http://faculty2.ucmerced.edu/ebrown22/SMRBJ09_IEEE.pdf)) This should be roughly comparable to the transient decrease in particle spacing in a shear thickening fluid that is being compressed beyond its relaxation rate.